# Initramfs failure, Ubuntu 10.10 32bit during boot

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10, initramfs

I am getting `initramfs` error. I found [Ubuntu server won't boot, stops at initramfs](https://serverfault.com/questions/187867/ubuntu-server-wont-boot-stops-at-initramfs) link on ServerFault. But the solution didn't worked for me.

Please suggest the solution.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably, the required hardware support is not contained in your kernel nor present as a module in your initial RAM disk in order to boot your system.

Comment: I have a question - did it work before or it's brand new thing you're trying?

Comment: This error some times came to me but i ignored it before but now it is urgent for me to resolve. I answered my own question. Thanks

Comment: The error you've cited is far, FAR too generic to be of any help in the future. The solution you've posted is potentially dangerous (removing the filesystem journal) and unlikely to be of any benefit to future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153852/can-not-boot-initramfs-error). This worked perfectly for me.

**Solution**

I have the same problem...I did some commands in the terminal after logging into the live cd

**The following step is for removing the i-node**

In the terminal I typed

```
sudo debugfs -w /dev/sda1
debugfs 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
debugfs: clri <8>
debugfs: quit
```

After that restart the system and again boot into  the live cd

In the terminal type

```
sudo fsck -yv /dev/sda1
```

It will work.....definitely

**After logging into the desktop in the terminal type the following commands**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get check
```

For More Details visit the tutorial page

http://dcageek.blogspot.com/2013/02/ubuntu-initramfs-error-during-boot.html

For More Visit details

http://dcageek.blogspot.com